# UISegmentedControl use ViewController some issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to take UIViewControllers using an UISegmentedControl,but not succeeded.

I am setting the selected segment index by using the method:

[image]

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SessionViewController *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ContactListViewController *ContactView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedControl *segmentedTemp;

self.segmentTitle = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"one", @"two"]];
self.segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
self.segmentTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.segmentTitle.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
self.segmentTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
[self.segmentTitle addTarget:self action:@selector(switchView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentTitle;

 - (void)switchView
 {
   for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
     [subview removeFromSuperview];
 }
   switch (_segmentTitle.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0: {
        [self.view addSubview:_mainView.view];
        _mainView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        [self.view addSubview:_ContactView.view];
        _ContactView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

        break;
    }
      default:
        break;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write you action Like

Use -(IBAction) And :(id)Sender

```
- (IBAction)sagmentBtn:(id)sender{


   switch (self.mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
       case 0:
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;
    default:
        break;
     }

}
```